# How Can I Collect Data from a Button in PowerApps

Tags: office365, powerapps

I'm trying to create a form in PowerApps where a user clicks a button (called "I Agree") and the button then:
-navigates to a thank-you screen (works fine)
-captures that users login info and saves it in some type of list or database that I can reference later (no dice)

If not possible to complete this from a button, proposed workarounds?

Thanks,
Jesse

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. A few steps you'll take for that:

- Create a connection to your database, selecting the table that you will want to use to save the user's information
- If you want more information than the [User function](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/tutorials/function-user/) gives you(full name, e-mail) then you'll need to add a connection to the Office 365 connector where you can get more information. If name / e-mail are enough, you can skip this step
- Add a button in the screen, setting its text property to "I Agree"

On the button's OnSelect property, perform the actions that you want. You can use `;` (or `;;` in locales where the number separator is `,`) to perform multiple actions in a single rule. Below is an example, assuming that the DB table has two columns (Name, Email) and is named `UsersTable`):

```
Collect(UsersTable, { Name: User().FullName, Email: User().Email }); Navigate(ThankYouScreen, ScreenTransition.Fade)
```